# How to find entity from context with two foreign keys?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, blazor

I want to delete an entity, which has 1 primary key and 2 foreign keys. The problem is I only know the 2 foreign keys. Is there an Methode or something else, to find the entity, which I want to delete?

Here is my entity:

[image]

And here is my method:

[image]

```
In my Database:
BookmarkId = 7,
SeriesId = 1,
UserId = 1

But the entity (bookmark) is:
BookmarkId = 0,
SeriesId = 1,
UserId = 1
```

because I dont know the BookmarkId for every single one.

Hope there is enough information and somebody knows what I need to do.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strong indication that Bookmark has the wrong key.  If its key were simply (SeriesId, UserId) then you could create a stub entity, mark it as Deleted and SaveChanges.

As it is you must query the Bookmark from the database to discover its BookmarkId.

Comment: Yeah first I wanted to do the entity keyless, but I had some problem with it and changed it, that I have an key. I did it with an query for the moment, but maybe I rework all of this.

Comment: The entity needs a key, but it should be a compound key made up of the two foreign key properties.